# Angular app Won't load on IE8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I'm developing an app with angular. 
There is no much Javascript code, since it only make up.

It work fine in chrome/firefox/safari/ie9+

In IE8 it won't load the page, it throws several angular exceptions before the page loads.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978533/angularjs-1-3-page-wont-load-in-ie8) post and tried, the errors are less, but there are some yet.

Angular does not have I8 support anymore? Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978533/angularjs-1-3-page-wont-load-in-ie8?lq=1

Comment: Yes, that is the exact same link I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular 1.3+ does not support ie8 anymore. If you want to use it on IE8, use angular 1.2 and below